# How to properly store a complex jquery selector chain for re-use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

tl;dr? ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj6Ap/)***

I have a scenario where I need to re-issue a jquery selector because the dom changes. The selector is non trivial.

```
$("#protocol :first-child").nextUntil('.sampleDetails','.detailHolder')
```

To accomplish this I attempted to break it into its parts and store them for re-use:

```
var selector = [];
selector.push("#protocol :first-child");
selector.push("nextUntil"); 
selector.push(['.sampleDetails','.detailHolder']);
```

And this way when I needed to build the selector I could use

```
$(selector[0])[selector[1]](selector[2]);
```

However, the argument for `nextUntil` requires two parameters. Using the array does not work, and using "'.sampleDetails','.detailHolder'" did not work as well. I tried to use `call` and `apply` but got an error saying that `"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'pushStack' "`.

What is the proper way to store this type of selector chain?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Why not just `.apply(selector[2][0], selector[2][1]);`?

Comment: @Ian: That wouldn't make `this` what it should be.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ahh yes, `this`, forgot about that. And nevermind, I mixed up how `apply` is used anyways

Comment: Add `this` as first arg and change `apply` to `call`.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - That will throw an exception.

Comment: OK, I paraphrased on `this`. Should read "Add whatever as first arg (which will be referced as `this` inside the called function) and change apply to call".

Comment: OK, sorry `selector[2]` is already an array - doh!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Surely the easy way to do this is with a function, not a complex array of selectors?

```
var getElements = function() {
    return $("#protocol :first-child").nextUntil('.sampleDetails','.detailHolder');
};
```

And you can then call it as many times as you like:

```
var elements = getElements();
```

Or even:

```
getElements().show();
```

Comment: Nice. Lol, not sure why I didn't think of that. Works: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SsLC3/).

Comment: Wow, I was trying to make the selector string array work, and totally didn't even think of this.  YAY for over-engineering!

Comment: This was my first thought but it seemed tooooo obvious.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot too obvious to be answered? `;-D`

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot If your first thought seems obvious... it's probably right! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Whilst lonesomeday's answer is the way to go, you can use your original approach with;

```
jQuery.fn[selector[1]].apply($(selector[0]), selector[2]);
```

This uses the [`apply()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), and translates to;

```
jQuery.fn.nextUntil.apply($('#protocol :first-child'), ['.sampleDetails','.detailHolder']);
```